# Cartesian product using Dask

Tags: python, pandas, dask

I'm trying to migrate a code from Pandas to Dask, and there's a part of the code that's written like this:

```
it1 = np.array([1, 2, 3])
it2 = np.array(['a', 'b', 'c'])
it3 = np.array([10, 20, 30])
pd.MultiIndex.from_product([it1, it2, it3])
```

but Dask doesn't support MultiIndex, and I'm not finding a good way of replicating this behavior in Dask. Any idea how I could replicate this behavior?

**Edit:**

Some clarifications, the data I'm working on is larger than memory, so pandas won't make the cut, also, the indexes are unimportant and are later reset in the code, what is really important is to get a Dataframe with the Cartesian product of the list items.

Comment: It would be helpful to see how ```iterable_i``` (```i=1,2,3```) actually look like,

Comment: They are all numpy arrays

Comment: @SergedeGossondeVarennes I've edited to make it look more like the code I have

Answer (score 0):

Dask does not support Multiindex, but an alternative would be to drop indices from your datframe. Here is an example on how you could proceed. Suppose you have your dataframe as you gave above:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

it1 = np.array([1, 2, 3])
it2 = np.array(['a', 'b', 'c'])
it3 = np.array([10, 20, 30])

data = np.ravel(np.random.rand(9,3))

idx2 = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([it1, it2, it3])
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data, index=idx2)
```

[image]
Then, you can either specify which level index to drop:

```
df2.index = df2.index.droplevel(2)
```

or selection from the end

```
df2.index = df2.index.droplevel(-1)
```

[image]

Then do your thing with dask.

Comment: The data I'm working on doesn't fit in memory, that's why I need a Dask solution, the  Multiindex is not really the important part, but creating a new data frame as a Cartesian product of the iterators is. Later in code, the indexes are reset

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do it like this:

```
it1 = np.array([1, 2, 3])
it2 = np.array(['a', 'b', 'c'])
it3 = np.array([10, 20, 30])

it1_temp = dd.from_array(it1, columns="it1")
it1_temp["key"] = 1

it2_temp = dd.from_array(it1, columns="it2")
it12_temp["key"] = 1

it3_temp = dd.from_array(it1, columns="it3")
it3_temp["key"] = 1

result = dd.merge(it1_temp, it2_temp, on="key")
result = dd.merge(it3_temp, result, on="key")
result = result.drop("key", axis=1)
```